# Grammatically and meaningfully, what does “yet” function in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

NEW SANCTIONS The United Nations Security council voted to impose the most punishing sanctions **yet** on North Korea.

Question: what does “yet” function in the sentence? Grammatically and semantically?

Answer (score 3):

It's an adverb and, in this sense, it means "thus far".

Comment: But as i know, that yet is used with present perfect. How it is possible to indicate the meaning of “thus far” of past tense “voted” ?

Comment: Well, it could have been written in the present perfect above, but the implicit clause above is "...to impose **[what are]** the most punishing sanctions **yet** on North Korea," i.e., "they are the most punishing sanctions **thus far** on North Korea."

Comment: "The most severe punishment is **yet** to come." Here it means "at this time".

Comment: Perhaps some further examples will help. You might think of *yet* with the meaning *as of now.* Usain Bolt *ran* the fastest time ever recorded at the time he ran it (as of then). *As of now* (or "thus far," or "so far"), it is still the fastest time that has ever been recorded, so nobody has broken the record *yet.* Maybe that helps a bit?